# SqlServer 2005 Ok, MSLocalDb 2016 Error : LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two server : production server SQL Server 2005 and my test server (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB 2016

I use .Net Framework 4.5.2 and EntityFramework 6, in a Linq request I do :

```
query.Select(l => l.s.Field1 + l.s.Field2).ToList();
```

- Field1 : string
- Field2 : Nullable< int >

On the production server it works, the sql generated is :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Field1] IS NULL) THEN N''
            ELSE [Extent1].[Field1] END +
       CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Field2] IS NULL) THEN N''
            ELSE  CAST( [Extent1].[Field2] AS nvarchar(max))
       END AS [C1]
```

but on the local server I have this error :

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I know how to solve my problem.

1. I put my fields in a anonymous object, ToList() and I concatenate
   the fields after the ToList()
2. another solution is :

   ```
   query.Select(l => l.s.Field1 + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)l.s.Field2).Trim())
   ```

But I would like to understand why I have this difference :

I have put the compatibiliy on my local server to 2008 same thing.

If I do :

- `Field2.Value` error :

  > Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
- `Field2.Value.ToString()` error :

  > LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

- This is a limitation of (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB ?
- After 2005 this kind of thing is not allowed ?
- There is an option to activate/desactivate the implicit conversion
  ?

Any clues are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

```
query.Select(l => l.s.Field1 + (l.s.Field2 ?? "").ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: This would only work if the fields were already strings, so it's pointless

Answer (score 0):

I found where my problem comes from. This is a simple version issue of EntityFramework: On my test I am in 6.0.0 and in production 6.1.3.

Sorry